# Object has no attribute JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print the output of an API into a local json file so I can search through the file.

I've tried looking at the type of `symbols` to see what the object type is but haven't had any luck. In statically typed languages I have an easier time troubleshooting due to knowing explicitly what the type is. Are there good ways to troubleshoot this type of problem moving forward?

```
symbols = urllib.request.urlopen("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/ref-data/symbols?format=json&token={}".format(key))

symbols.json.loads()
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(symbols, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

print(type(symbols))
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'json'
```

Comment: good way for this type of problem is to find documentation and read it.

Comment: in module `requests` you have `response.json()`

Comment: @furas I read the documentation but I couldn’t find any mention of what the method returns.

Comment: you can use `type(symbols)` to get its type. If it is class then you can use `dir(symbols)` to get its methods and properties. You can also check
`help(symbols)`

Comment: @furas yea the type was httpresponse so that wasn’t very helpful. I tried using dir already but when I get home I’ll look closer at the methods and properties. Maybe I missed it.

Comment: I don't believe the `urllib` module supports the `json` attribute. The example you gave looks like the `requests` package.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Json` is a library/package in python.

```
symbols.json.loads() # wrong statement
```

In order to work with json you have to import json packagae first in your file

```
import json
json.loads(symbols); # you have use statement like this.
```

You have to pass the variable or value to the `loads()` function.

Comment: I should of included the header of the file but I had import JSON. How come I can method chain certain things and in this case I have to pass the variable to it?

Comment: not sure what are you meant but if you have json imported in your file just try `json.loads(symbols)` and if your file didn't have json imported this method doesn't work

Comment: So why would I need to decode the ‘symbols’ data if the api returns the data in json format?

Comment: because the api return the data in json format and after that you have to handle that data with python. but python didn't understand json format it treated it as all strings value, and json values are strings. after that you are dumping your data and using `json.dump()` which is used to convert python objects to json format and `json.loads()` function is used to convert json values to python objects.

Comment: wow I’m stupid. I totally read that section and missed that statement. Lesson learned. Take more breaks when stuff to clear my head. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197781/discussion-between-rocket-man-and-abhishek-saini).

Answer (score 0):

```
# symbols.json.loads() #-> it is httpresponse no attribute json
json_data = json.load(symbols)
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(symbols, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23764764)